# Set image as label on ApexChart

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

I have a bar chart in my app. I want to set a image as the label instead of the highlighted texts.
I know that you can use image fill, however I want the image on the x-axis label instead. I couldn't find anything that helps. So. does anyone have any idea how I can accomplish that?

[image]

So far I've tried using the formatter, but it didn't work.

```
xaxis: {
    categories: labels,
    labels: {
        formatter: function (val) {
            const img = document.querySelector("img");
            img.src = val;
            return img;
        }
    }
},
```

It returns:

```
[object HTMLImageElement]
```

instead of actual img element that I wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can put **images** (especially JPEG or PNG) with clean code, even if you manipulate the DOM yourself. However, you may want to use **icons**. They are easy to integrate (thanks, SVG) and they represent a good alternative.

Below I give you an example with [Bootstrap Icons](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/). You should use the **"JS code point"** (e.g. [Browser Safari · Bootstrap Icons](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/icons/browser-safari/)).

```js
let options = {
  series: [{
    name: 'Browsers',
    data: [15, 20, 10]
  }],
  chart: {
    height: 350,
    type: 'bar'
  },
  xaxis: {
    categories: ['\uF7D4', '\uF7D6', '\uF7D5'], // <--- HERE
    labels: {
      style: {
        fontSize: '25px',
        fontFamily: 'Bootstrap-icons'
      },
      offsetY: 5
    }
  }
};

let chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector('#chart'), options);
chart.render();
```

```css
@import "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-icons/1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css";

.apexcharts-tooltip-title {
  font-family: "Bootstrap-icons" !important;
}

.apexcharts-xaxis-label {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>

<div id="chart"></div>
```

It works! Keep in mind **accessibility**, though...